# Cannot link my page to the router in node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

Can someone help me out? I am trying to connect my HTML page to the router, so that when I go to a certain link, I can render a certain HTML page. Right now, I am just trying to send something and nothing works. Here is a screenshot of my work:

[image: Screenshot]

My ultimate goal is to render `movie_info.html`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you don't have to render html pages. You can simply open html as static file.

Comment: How do I do that. And could you please help me fix my current problem?

Comment: you are not exporting your router ... add `module.exports = router;` at the end of the file ...

Comment: @RafDaniloff check the answer

Comment: Hey @RafDaniloff - to help people answer your question, can you put the code into the question and not the image of the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to render html pages. You can simply open html as static file.

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express(); // better instead
server.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/your_html_page_folder'));
server.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with ejs templates. first you have to install ejs

```
npm i ejs
```

then create a views folder in your main folder.In that folder save your file with .ejs extension.In your case movie_info.ejs

in movie_info.js do the following:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
// setting ejs as templating engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('movie_info');
});

app.listen(3000)
```

this will render your page.